# Get tz offset from string

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, python-datetime

I have a date which is in local time:

```
date: "2013-12-02 22:00:00"
```

and another value the tz:

```
timezone_offset: "GMT-0800"
```

If I : `dateutil.parser.parse(date).isoformat()` I will get:

```
"2013-12-02T22:00:00+0000"
```

---

I want to implement the `date` in ISO format with the tz info and get a result of:

```
"2013-12-02T22:00:00-0800"
```

Something close to: `parse(date,tzinfos=??).isoformat()` ? How can I get the tzinfo from the string `timezone_offset` ?

Comment: Where do you get the `parse` function from?

Comment: @jazzpi [dateutil.parser.parse()](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse("2013-12-02 22:00:00" + "GMT+0800")
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2013-12-02T22:00:00-08:00'
```

Note: the sign is reversed.

You could also do it using only stdlib:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("2013-12-02 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(-8*60, "GMT+0800"))
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2013-12-02T22:00:00-08:00'
```

where [`FixedOffset` is taken from `datetime` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed offset in minutes east from UTC."""

    def __init__(self, offset, name):
        self.__offset = timedelta(minutes = offset)
        self.__name = name

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
```

Here's the same using [`pytz` module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("2013-12-02 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> dt = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+8').localize(dt)
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2013-12-02T22:00:00-08:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches you could use:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dtnow = datetime.datetime.now();dtutcnow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> dtnow
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 9, 10, 48, 404000)
>>> dtutcnow
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 15, 10, 48, 404000)
>>> delta = dtnow - dtutcnow
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(-1, 64800)
>>> hh,mm = divmod((delta.days * 24*60*60 + delta.seconds + 30) // 60, 60)
>>> hh,mm
(-6, 0)
>>> "%s%+02d:%02d" % (dtnow.isoformat(), hh, mm)
'2013-11-12T09:10:48.404000-6:00'
```

Or this:

```
>>> import datetime, pytz # 3rd Party
>>> datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Central')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
'2013-11-12T09:15:20.688000-0600'
>>>
```

The main advantage of the second method is it makes your time string 'timezone aware'. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime):

> There are two kinds of date and time objects: “naive” and “aware”.
>   This distinction refers to whether the object has any notion of time
>   zone, daylight saving time, or other kind of algorithmic or political
>   time adjustment. Whether a naive datetime object represents
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other
>   timezone is purely up to the program, just like it’s up to the program
>   whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive
>   datetime objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost
>   of ignoring some aspects of reality.

Hope this helps!