# convert string to datetime

Tags: python, django, timezone

I have a date string which is in the form of `2016-03-15 14:41:48.901013+05:30`. I want to change it to a datetime object in the same format i.e `2016-03-17 14:41:48.901013+05:30`. Please help me in doing this.

I am using django 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Install [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

**Code:**

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("2016-03-15 14:41:48.901013+05:30")
```

Comment: I got `datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 15, 14, 41, 48, 901013, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))`  but I want the exact same format. How can I convert it now.?

Comment: I would suggest you look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32399344/3259815