# what is this time format ? 20151104101700-0800

Tags: python, ios, xml, time, format

I am parsing an xml file exported from iOS Health App. The records of start time has this format:

```
@startDate:20151104101700-0800
@endDate:20151104111700-0800

...

@startDate:20151002151700-0800
@endDate:20151003151700-0800
```

I am just wondering what does the part '15170-0800' stand for. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: It looks to me like four-digit year, two-digit month, two-digit day, then hours (in 24-hour clock), minutes, seconds.  The -0800 is probably a timezone specification (meaning UTC-8).  But this question is off-topic because it's not really about programming at all.

Comment: @BrenBarn its about how to parse a date sting. Seems kinda programy to me.

Comment: @tdelaney: The question doesn't ask anything about how to parse it.  It just asks about what it is.

Comment: @BrenBarn the question starts "I am parsing an xml file...". I take that to mean that OP wants to parse the date within the xml file.

Comment: @tdelaney: Yes, but there is no question about *how* to do it.  The question doesn't even mention any programming language.  If someone asks "I am writing a program to translate Spanish into English and I want to know what *yo no soy marinero* means", that doesn't make it a programming question.

Comment: I am not so sure if this is about program or not either. But I know I can get a good answer quickly if I ask the question here. And I have got the answer I need. I appreciate @Christian Witts for answering my question.

Comment: I appreciate @tdelaney for defensing my question.

Comment: I also appreciate @BrenBarn for sticking to a strict rule to make this place a useful site for all programmers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`20151002151700-0800` would be the format `CCYYMMDDHHMMSS-TZ`.

So, the `151700` portion of your question is the time, in Hours Minutes Seconds.
What follows after would be a + or -, and how many hours and minutes you're offset from UTC, so the `-0800` would be UTC-8 timezone.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a standard time format (such as [rfc 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.8)) or a default time format for a [Date Formatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) but it is easy to parse anyway.

The time format is [`%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("20151104101700-0800", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 4, 10, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600)))
```

Note: it differs from [@Christian Witts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604150/4279) (`-` is a part of the numerical utc offset).

Don't use the label `UTC-8` in the programming context; [it may be ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31078749/4279). If you don't know the timezone name such as `America/Los_Angeles`; just numeric offset (`-0800`) is less ambiguous.