# Printing datetime as pytz.timezone("Etc/GMT-5") yields incorrect result

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Consider the following example, where I take a naive datetime, make it timezone aware in UTC, and then convert to UTC-5:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(2019,3,7, 7,45)

d2 = pytz.utc.localize(d1)
print(f'UTC  : {d2}')

d3 = d2.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT-5'))
print(f'UTC-5: {d3}')
```

The output of this is:

> ```
> UTC  : 2019-03-07 07:45:00+00:00
> UTC-5: 2019-03-07 12:45:00+05:00
> ```

I would have expected the `UTC-5` time to be `02:45`, but the 5 hour offset is being **added** to UTC, rather than subtracted.

**Questions:**

- Why is the `'Etc/GMT-5'` offset applied to UTC +5 hours instead of -5 hours?
- How can I convert from `UTC` to `UTC-5`?

Comment: Related: [Timezone offset sign reversed by Python dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081559/190597)

Comment: Certainly seems to be, but the top answer in your linked question says the behavior is different between `dateutil` and `datetime`, while my observed behavior is counter to that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `pytz`, not just Python's `datetime`. 
[Like dateutil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081559/190597), pytz [uses the Olson tz database](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

The Olson tz database defines `Etc/GMT+N` timezones which [conform with the POSIX style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database):

> those zone names beginning with
>     "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from the standard ISO 8601 convention. In
>     the "Etc" area, zones west of GMT have a positive sign and those east have a
>     negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is 14 hours ahead of GMT.)

---

So, to convert UTC to a timezone with offset -5 you could use `Etc/GMT+5`:

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz

naive = DT.datetime(2019, 3, 7, 7, 45)
utc = pytz.utc
gmt5 = pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+5')
print(utc.localize(naive).astimezone(gmt5))

# 2019-03-07 02:45:00-05:00
```

Comment: Thank you for this - definitely cleared it up in my mind now!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in posix style systems, you have to use the inverse of the timezone offset. That means if you want to get `-5`, you have to use `GMT+5`.

```
d3 = d2.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+5'))
```

prints

```
UTC-5: 2019-03-07 02:45:00-05:00
```

Otherwise, you have to pass the `posix_offset` as true. This is in dateutil documentation;

> There is one notable exception, which is that POSIX-style time zones
>   use an inverted offset format, so normally GMT+3 would be parsed as an
>   offset 3 hours behind GMT. The tzstr time zone object will parse this
>   as an offset 3 hours ahead of GMT. If you would like to maintain the
>   POSIX behavior, pass a True value to posix_offset.

https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzstr

Comment: You've linked to dateutil, whereas I'm using datetime. Do you have a link to datetime docs which explain this behavior?

Comment: I couldn’t see the docs specifically for datetime. I’ll post if I see. However, this posix thing is not specific to dateutil.