# How to apply a 'tzoffset' to a datetime object in a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am kind of completely lost...

I have instanced a panda dataframe in python with read_csv() function.
I had to extract in a list the column containing timestamps and make some cleaning.
This list now looks like:

```
0     Sat Mar 30 2019 21:00:00 GMT+0100
1     Sat Mar 30 2019 22:00:00 GMT+0100
2     Sat Mar 30 2019 23:00:00 GMT+0100
...
```

I convert it back to 'datetime' object and add it back in my dataframe with following command:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_timestamps)
```

df['date'] now looks like:

```
0     2019-03-30 21:00:00-01:00
1     2019-03-30 22:00:00-01:00
2     2019-03-30 23:00:00-01:00
```

Before or after, I would like to actually apply the timezone offset, so as to have:

```
0     2019-03-30 20:00:00+00:00
1     2019-03-30 21:00:00+00:00
2     2019-03-30 22:00:00+00:00
```

Please, how can I obtain that?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Have a good evening,

Bests,

Pierrot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trouble is a known *trouble* with dateutil.

See:

https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/70

[Timezone offset sign reversed by Python dateutil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078749/timezone-offset-sign-reversed-by-python-dateutil)

https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/968

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.DateOffset` on `hours` with `utc=True` as follows

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_timestamps, utc=True) - pd.DateOffset(hours=2)

Out[860]:
0   2019-03-30 20:00:00+00:00
1   2019-03-30 21:00:00+00:00
2   2019-03-30 22:00:00+00:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

If you want to strip the timezone completely, try this

```
import pytz    
df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(my_timestamps).dt.tz_convert(pytz.FixedOffset(-120))
                                           .dt.tz_localize(None))

Out[863]:
0   2019-03-30 20:00:00
1   2019-03-30 21:00:00
2   2019-03-30 22:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer. Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. This timezone has DST. So offset, can be -1 hour, as on the example given, or -2 hours. I would like to simply apply the offset given. I am so surprised so maybe I don't understand: why the offset I get cannot be applied as is: -1h. In your code, you offset by -2 hours. If tzoffset is -1, to get UTC time, you should substract 1 hour to current time. Is the timezone correctly initialized?